# concatenate image in python

Tags: python, opencv, wavelet

any body  can  help  identify  the  problem   here?

i have  the code here to concatenate H and L   to  present  an image  and  whenever i run the code  i get :

```
np.concatenate((H,L))

>> ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

but i don't know why H  and L  are zero dimensional  .thanks in advance

```
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np
c1=0.5
c2=0.25

img1=cv2.imread("Penguin-cartoon.png") ## Genuine Image

img=cv2.imread("Penguin-cartoon.png",cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)    #gray_scaled Image
A=img.astype(np.int16)
D=[]
C=[]
x,y=img.shape

B = np.empty((x,y), dtype = np.int16)
for j in range(1,y):
  for i in range (0,x/2 -1 ):
    if i==0:
        P=A[j,2*i+2]*c1

        B[j,2*i+1]=A[j,2*i+1]-P
    elif i==x/2:
        U=B[j,2*i-1]*c2
        B[j,2*i]=A[j,2*i]+U
    else :
        P=(A[j,2*i-1]+A[j,2*i+2])*c1
        B[j,2*i+1]=A[j,2*i+1]-P
        U=(B[j,2*i-1]+B[j,2*i+1])*c2
        B[j,2*i]=A[j,2*i]+U

for j in range(1,y):
    for i in range (0,x/2 -1 ):
      D=B[j,2*i-1]
      C=B[j,2*i]

H=D.astype(np.uint8)
L=C.astype(np.uint8)
np.concatenate((H,L))
```

Comment: Specify what you mean by concatenate. Put them side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects `H`, `L` you are concatenating are scalars not arrays, hence the error. Their assignment in the last `for` loop does not make sens,

```
for j in range(1,y):
   for i in range (0,x/2 -1 ):
      D=B[j,2*i-1]
      C=B[j,2*i]

H=D.astype(np.uint8)
L=C.astype(np.uint8)
```

BTW, you should check some tutorials on the use of numpy. The idea is that in most cases, you can use vectorized numpy operations instead of iterating over the pixels of your array in Python. The former is much faster.